# Wordpress, Meta Slider navigation control don't appear

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, plugins

I'm developing a theme for an online store from scratch, I used underscores and Bootstrap and now I want insert a slider with the MetaSlider Plugin.

The problem is that I have no controls, and also the slider is not working, get stuck in the first image.

The curious thing is that in the admin page when I click on "save and previsualize" it works perfectly.

I inspected the code and I realized that the `<ul>` element that contains the controls is not there, so is not a css problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check if there is no any conflict with another plugin. It may cause if there is another version of jQuery library that embedded in the page.